# SSH log file contains only binary data?

Tags: ssh

I'm practicing with some web application vulnerabilities in my test environemnt, and one of the things I am trying to use the SSH log file with a LFI vulnerability. However, I'm noticing that even after SSH'ing into my vulnerable box, the only thing that changes in /var/log is wtmp and lastlog, both which only contain binary data.

I thought the /var/auth.log file would be updated each time I tried to login, but it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you set the LogLevel to for your sshd ?

Comment: It's set at "Info"

Comment: Also remember to look at the enabled logging level in your logging daemon (usually syslog).